# Does `TransferUtility` from the android Amazon AWS Mobile SDK run in its own `Service`?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-service, aws-sdk, awss3transferutility

I am using `TransferUtility` to upload big files to S3.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/s3-integration-transferutility.html)

Can anyone confirm that `TransferUtility` creates its own Android `Service` for this?

Files are big, and I need to perform the upload in an Android `Service` to avoid the app to be killed.
`TransferUtility` exposes an asynchronous API, but it's not clear if it creates an Android `Service` or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the past when I used to use AWS, I always wrapped my calls in a JobScheduler. But you should probably wrap it in a [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#additional-resources).

```
public class UploadWorker extends Worker {

    public UploadWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
      // Do the work here.

      transferLargeFilesToAws()

      // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
      return Result.success()
    }
}
```